# Headless GPT2 Model from Hugging Face throws Error on Saving - How to add input and output layers, and custom PositionalEmbedding

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, huggingface-transformers

I want to use GPT2 for a regression task on a sequence data so trying to figure out the headless TFGPT2 from Hugging Face, with code as below:

```
configuration = GPT2Config(n_embd = embed_dim, n_head=num_heads)
base_model = TFGPT2Model(configuration)
input_shape = (1, embed_dim)
input1 = layers.Input(shape=input_shape, dtype=tf.float32)
positional_encoding = PositionalEmbedding(sequence_length, embed_dim)
decoder_inputs = positional_encoding(input1)
Z = base_model(None, inputs_embeds=decoder_inputs)
outputs = layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.Dense(embed_dim, activation="relu"))(Z.last_hidden_state)
model = keras.Model(input1, outputs)
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(beta_1=0.9,beta_2=0.98,epsilon=1.0e-9), metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()])
history = model.fit(dataset, validation_data=val_dataset, epochs=epoch_len,verbose=1)
tf.keras.saving.save_model(model, r'/drive/model_huggingface')
```

Also note that I am using a custom PositionalEmbedding class as well, hence the optional inputs_embeds argument passed to the model.
This model trains and learns the data, although when attempting the save throws the error:

```
AssertionError: Tried to export a function which references an 'untracked' resource. TensorFlow objects (e.g. tf.Variable) captured by functions must be 'tracked' by assigning them to an attribute of a tracked object or assigned to an attribute of the main object directly. See the information below:
    Function name = b'__inference_signature_wrapper_452514'
    Captured Tensor = <ResourceHandle(name="transformer/h_._0/ln_1/gamma/186", device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", container="Anonymous", type="tensorflow::Var", dtype and shapes : "[ DType enum: 1, Shape: [300] ]")>
    Trackable referencing this tensor = <tf.Variable 'transformer/h_._0/ln_1/gamma:0' shape=(300,) dtype=float32>
    Internal Tensor = Tensor("452144:0", shape=(), dtype=resource)
```

Which I assume due to me adding either the head and the custom layer to this model. Please let me know your thoughts about my interpretations about how to implement this model.